# PHP Having trouble decoding multilevel JSON array

Tags: php, json

I am making a cheat detecting small software piece for personal use in PHP, the code scans all files in a directory, sorts out all of the `.JSON` files and then will parse and return some values. I have one function working to tell me what the version number is from the `JSON` file:

```
function scan_Versions($dir) {
  $array = array();
  $rdi = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
  foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($rdi) as $filename => $file) {
    if(!is_dir($filename)) {
      $path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
      $ext = $path_parts["extension"]. PHP_EOL;
      if (strpos($ext, "json") !== false) {
        $str = file_get_contents($filename);
        $json = json_decode(utf8_decode($str), true);
        array_push($array,$json['id']);
      }
    }
  }
  return $array;
}
```

When executed it will scan the files, and get data from a `JSON` file like this: http://pastebin.com/3VdEZW43 (It gets the first `id` part of the `JSON`)

I need a function like the one above to retrieve the data from:

```
"libraries": [
    {
      "name": "oshi-project:oshi-core:1.1", <----- I NEED THIS!!!!!!!!!!
      "downloads": {
        "artifact": {
          "url": "https://libraries.[REMOVED].net/oshi-project/oshi-core/1.1/oshi-core-1.1.jar",
          "sha1": "9ddf7b048a8d701be231c0f4f95fd986198fd2d8",
          "size": 30973
        }
      }
    }.......
```

From the`"name":` that contains: `oshi-project:oshi-core:1.1`. Can someone help me do this?

Comment: but you want ALL the "name" for ALL the json files? I think it's really simple, you already have all you need in the `$json` variable, just do something with it..

Comment: @Johnny Yeah, I'm having trouble getting the value because it's like in another array and PHP gives me errors when I try something `$json["libraries"]["name"][0]`

Comment: You need to clarify what you are after. The json in your pastebin creates an array whose 'location' key is a numerically indexed array with 33 items in it. Which one are you after? Really don't know what you need to extract.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to add a comment (new here), but you would want

```
$json["libraries"][0]["name"]
```

not

```
$json["libraries"]["name"][0]
```

according to the pastebin link.